# Output formatting: too much whitespace in gfortran

Tags: formatting, fortran, output, gfortran

Using gfortran 4.6.  This code:

```
PROGRAM f1
IMPLICIT NONE

INTEGER :: i=1, j=3

WRITE(*,*) "integer i is ", i, ", and j is ", j, "."
END PROGRAM f1
```

produces this console output, which has way too much whitespace:

```
 integer i is            1 , and j is            3 .
```

Is there some setting I can set so that there is no space before the first token ("integer"), and so the whitespace between tokens is just one space?  I know one fix is

```
WRITE(*,'(A,I1,A,I1,A)') "integer i is ", i, ", and j is ", j, "."
```

but this seems very cumbersome to have to do every time I have a print statement - would rather it be somewhat more like C++ where you explicitly write any whitespace in the output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

List-directed IO, i.e, `write (*, *)` is meant as a convenience.   There are no settings to change its behavior.  Different compilers will produce different output. Instead you can, as you have identified, use formatted IO.  In this case you can use `I0` as the format, which will produce the required number of digits, while `I1` will only output single-digit integers. Which is OK if those are the largest values that will be output.

```
WRITE(*,  '( "integer i is ", I0, ", and j is ", I0, "." )' )  i, j
```

Answer (score 2):

You may try some more universal format and re-use it

```
    fmt = "(*(1x,g0))"

    write(*,fmt) whatever1, whatever2
```