# How to format an integer to have only the needed size?

Tags: fortran, string-formatting, fortran90

I have been experimenting with the following code:

```
program hello
    write(*,"(i9)") 10
end program hello
```

and varying the format string, trying to make write output a string just the size needed to represent the integer number, but so far I was unable to manage it. How to write 'fit' integers in Fortran?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Output formatting: too much whitespace in gfortran](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24844250/output-formatting-too-much-whitespace-in-gfortran)

Comment: There are several other potential duplicates, but many rely on `I0` which is not F90.  Do you really need a Fortran 90 answer?

Comment: Well, if possible without me having to write my own formatting subroutine, I prefer. I am used to rely on standards...

Comment: `I0` has been standard for twenty years.  [My comment was not "standard Fortran?", but "Does it need to be Fortran 90 and not later?" based on your tag choice.]

Comment: Specifically, don't you mind Fortran 95? (in my opinion you really should not)

Comment: Understood now. I myself don't mind using Fortran 95, and judging for what you are saying, probably nobody will.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `I0` edit descriptor is the correct way for output of integers with the correct width.  This was introduced in Fortran 95.  All current Fortran compilers which were Fortran 90 compilers have been updated to Fortran 95 years ago.