# Removing leading zeros from Fortran string from int

Tags: fortran

I have a user-defined integer `x` which I am casting to a string 'xs' as

```
integer :: x
read (*,*) x
character xs*4
write (xs, '(I4.4)') x
```

If `x` is less than 4 digits in length, i.e. `x=25`, then `xs` becomes

```
0025
```

I don't want this, and simply want `xs='25'`. However, I do not know before hand how long `x` is actually going to be (it is set by the user), just that it will be at most 4 digits. Can I remove the leading zeros? Can I change them to leading whitespace, and then call `trim()`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format an integer to have only the needed size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28728882/how-to-format-an-integer-to-have-only-the-needed-size)

Comment: The answer found by @veryreverie probably does exactly what you want, if I understand you correctly, but I think it worth noting that an edit descriptor of simply I4 will write the digits padded to length 4 with white space, i.e. no leading zeros. In fact I would say I4.4 is a rather uncommon format descriptor, in my experience I4 is much more commonly be used.

Comment: @IanBush, I use `I4.4` when creating data file names for the frames in animations, e.g., `write(name,"(A,I4.4,A)") "frame", i, ".dat"`.  Then, at least on Unix-like systems the files are listed in proper order with `animate frame*.dat`

Comment: @steve agreed it has its uses, just I would suspect i4 is more common

Comment: Although using `I0` would be appropriate, you still get `25  ` (with two trailing blanks) because you're writing to a length-four character variable. Also, as in the question you could use `I4` to get leading whitespace, but instead of `trim` (which again won't do any good because the character variable will still be of the same length, so padded with trailing blanks) you'd want `adjustl`.