# Fortran write to file works weirdly with different compilers

Tags: fortran, cray

So I have a snippet of code writing 9 variables to a file:

```
if (rank == 0) then
    write (filehandle,*) a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i
endif
```

But the code gives me different results on different machines / compilers:
If I use a PathScale compiler on a Cray cluster, I get:

```
5.444445          0.0000000E+00      0.0000000E+00      1.5010493E-04    
1.4887122E-04      2.5604754E-09      0.0000000E+00     -4.7524699E-07    
0.0000000E+00
```

(newline after every x columns)

But if I use a GNU compiler on a different cluster, I get:

```
5.444445          0.0000000E+00      0.0000000E+00      1.5010493E-04      1.4887122E-04      2.5604754E-09      0.0000000E+00     -4.7524699E-07     0.0000000E+00
```

(no newline and the code works as expected)

My makefile for both the compilers looks as such:

```
# PathScale
FC = ftn
OPTFC = -Ofast -cpp
CC = cc
CFLAGS = -O3

# GNU
FC = mpif90
OPTFC = -O3 -funroll-loops -ftree-vectorize -fcray-pointer -cpp
CC = mpicc
CFLAGS = -O3
```

I need the file write to work as it does in the second case. Because of system admin constraints, I cannot install different compilers on the Cray. Has anyone seen this before / know what the problem might be? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Such as https://stackoverflow.com/q/24844250.  Essentially, if you want control over how your output looks you have to use an explicit format.

Comment: that fixed it, sorry for the repost!