# Fortran Print Statement formatting, too many white spaces

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran90

The Fortran program I am writing is to add two integers together and get a sum, I have to print it out as "4+5=9", whereas 4 and 5 are user inputs. I ran into some problems of printing out too many unnecessary spaces in the print statement. So I did some researches and then I found a solution. But it keeps telling me the syntax is wrong in the PRINT statement and I have no idea why and how. Please help me with this situation. Thank you

I used the solution provided by this link: [Output formatting: too much whitespace in gfortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24844250/output-formatting-too-much-whitespace-in-gfortran)

```
PROGRAM SumProgram
IMPLICIT NONE

   !Define and initialize variables
   integer :: IntegerOne, IntegerTwo, Sum
   IntegerOne = 0
   IntegerTwo = 0
   Sum = 0

   !Prompt the user for inputs
   print *,' Enter the two Integers to be added together: '
   READ(*,*) IntegerOne, IntegerTwo

   !Do the Calculation
   Sum = IntegerOne + IntegerTwo

   PRINT (*, '(I0, "+", I0, "=", I0)') IntegerOne, IntegerTwo, Sum

END PROGRAM
```

I am expecting the output of "4+5=9"

Comment: The linked question and answers on which this question is based all use `write` rather than `print`, so I have voted to close this as a typo.  If you can rewrite the question to clearly give the error message from the compiler then the question would be more useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your syntax is good for the `WRITE` statement, but `PRINT` is like

```
 PRINT '(I0, "+", I0, "=", I0)', IntegerOne, IntegerTwo, Sum
```

but I find

```
 PRINT '(5g0)', IntegerOne, "+", IntegerTwo, "=", Sum
```

easier to read. (If you can't use `g0`, use `'(i0,a,i0,a,i0)'`.)

Or just exchange the `PRINT` for `WRITE`... I personally always use write and only use print for temporary debugging messages. It makes them easy to find.

Remember that the basic forms are

```
 PRINT *, "Hello"
```

vs.

```
 WRITE(*,*) "Hello"
```

so the forms with explicit format must conform to them.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is very helpful!